# Assembly. How to enter string and move it into variable (MASM)

Tags: assembly, x86

I have this code:

```
masm 
model small
.data
Mystr   db  'sssssssdsdsdsdsdsdsdddddddddddddd' 
minb db ?                             
sum db  ?
.code
;------------Процедуры_начало------------
mac macro x, y, z
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dh, y
    mov dl, x 
    int 10h
    mov ah, 09h
    mov bl, z ;
    int 10h
endm 
mac2 macro ex
    mov ah, 09h
    mov al, ex
    mov bh,0
    mov bl, 1 
    int 10h
endm
; clear screen BIOS
clrs    proc    near
        mov     ax,0600h
        mov     bh,07h
        mov     cx,0000
        mov     dx,184fh
        int     10h
        mov ax,0
        mov bx,0
        mov dx,0
        mov cx,0
        ret
clrs    endp
compare proc 
    cmp al, 10
    jl  @@metka
    add al, 37h 
    mac2 al
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h 
    ret
@@metka:
    add al, 30h
    mac2 al
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h     
    ret
endp
vivod_number proc
    mov AL, sum  
    and al, 0f0h
    ror al, 4 
    call compare 
    mov al, sum
    and al, 0fh
    call compare 
    ret
endp
calc proc
    mov SI, 0                           ;j
    mov DI, 0                           ;i
    mov AL, 0                           ;sum
    mov CL, 0FFh                        ;min
@while_OUT: 
    cmp Mystr[DI], 0 
    je @EndWhile_OUT
    mov SI, 0
    mov AL, 0
@while_IN:
    mov BL, Mystr[SI]
    cmp BL, 0 
    je @EndWhile_IN
    mov BL, Mystr[DI]
    cmp Mystr[SI],BL; 
    jne @IfNot_1; 
    inc AL
@IfNot_1:
    inc SI
    jmp @while_IN
@EndWhile_IN:
    cmp CL, AL 
    jna @IfNot_2 
    mov CL, AL
    mov BL, Mystr[DI]
    mov minb, BL
@IfNot_2:
    inc DI
    jmp @while_OUT
@EndWhile_OUT:
    dec AL
    mov sum, AL
    ret
endp

vivod_leter proc
    mac 39,12,1
    mov DX,0
    mov dl, minb 
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h 
    call vivod_number
    mac 42,12,0
    ret
endp

programm:
    mov AX, @data
    mov DS, AX
    mov ah,0ah
    int 21h

    call clrs
    call calc
    call vivod_leter
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h   
end programm
```

This code searches the **MIN** symbol in the string. It works, if I declared **string** in the .data
But I need to enter **string** from keyboard.
So, my question: 
How enter with keyboard string and move It to the variable Mystr. For next actions. Please modify my code with comments. Thanks a lot and sorry for my English ^^

Comment: *Please modify my code with comments* No.

Comment: -1 If you can't write comments to your own code, then it is not your code at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using DOS operating system you can use DOS function 0Ah to read from standard input.

```
mov ax, @data  ;this line may depend on actual assembler (check for exact masm syntax if it doesn't work)
mov ds, ax
mov dx, Mystr ; now ds:dx is pointing to Mystr string
              ; some assemblers accept mov dx, offset Mystr or similar syntax
mov ah, 0Ah ; Function 0Ah
    int 21h     ;invoke the DOS function
```